# Disable some of the Right-Click options In HTML5 Video?

Tags: html, video

Using HTML5 video, right click presents some options and I'd like to disable/hide *some* of them .. can that be done ? Or is it all or nothing? I've seen how to disable completely .. but was hoping for customization if possible using CSS or JS but without 3rd party packages ...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It doesn't matter why .. the question is whether there is a way or not .. but one reason is my video does not have sound, so having the option to mute / unmute is unneeded ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(ev){
    if(ev.target.nodeName=='VIDEO')
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```